# Firebase Database content deletion

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

In my project there are two databases in Firebase. One is the general database named `BlogPosts` for all the posts and one is named `UserPosts` for posts filtered under specific user. From `BlogPosts` I can get necessary data so that I can go to the specific post in `UserPosts` (that I have done in the document I have added here). I want to make a system so that when from home page (where `BlogPosts` are retrieved) I delete some post it will delete the data from both `BlogPosts` and `UserPosts` from Firebase database. But the system is getting crashed every time I  run my app and try to delete some post.

Here is my specific code:

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                  if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                 {
                       //get the profile id from BlogPosts post so that we can reach the same post in Userposts
                        String profileid = dataSnapshot.child("ProfileId").getValue().toString();

                      profiledb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                                .getReference().child("UserPosts").child(id).child(profileid);

                                                        }
                                                    }

            @Override
                   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                  }
         })   ;


             profiledb.removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                              @Override
                              public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                              databaseReference.removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                               @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {


                               ProfileFragment prf = new ProfileFragment();

                              android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                              fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, prf).commit();


                                                            }
                                                        });


                                                    }
                                                });
```

The error is given below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.removeValue()' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.zub.projectFirebase.SinglePostFragment$2$4$1.onMenuItemClick(SinglePostFragment.java:327)
```

Comment: databaseReference is the reference to the post in the BlogPosts database.

Comment: You have to provide a different database reference for all your transactions

Comment: Please explain it.

Comment: See my provided answer. Put the code to for deleting `profiledb` into where you get its database reference. by this, it will get the reference first before deleting. Where you are wrong is running the code differently. In a case where the first transaction is too heavy to load, it will continue with the other transactions, and making the db ref to be null because it does not complete before trying another

Comment: At which line of code are you getting this error? Please responde with @.

Comment: @Ineedajob the app is still crashing. Surprisingly the post that i want to delete is deleted from both the databases. But the app still crashes.

Comment: @AlexMamo since both the databases remove the post that I delete I guess the error is on "databaseReference.removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>()" in the updated code of Ineedajob. The app crashes just after it removes the post from both the databases.

Comment: "I guess", no you need to be sure.

Comment: @AlexMamo Ijust found where the problem is. There is a parent fragment SingleFragment from which this specific fragment is started. The SingleFragment uses data of the post. When I delete the post SingleFragment cant retrieve the data. Thus gives NullPointerException. One thing I dont understand is I have left SingleFragment to the new fragment and makes the remove operation. So why there is error in SingleFragment? And please give the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you are wrong is running the code differently. In a case where the first transaction is too heavy to load, it will continue with the other transactions, and making the `db` `ref` to be `null` because it does not complete before trying another
So, Put the code to for deleting `profiledb` into where you get its database reference. by this, it will get the reference first before deleting.

```
 databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                  if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                 {
                       //get the profile id from BlogPosts post so that we can reach the same post in Userposts
                        String profileid = dataSnapshot.child("ProfileId").getValue().toString();

                      profiledb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                                .getReference().child("UserPosts").child(id).child(profileid);

         profiledb.removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new 
         OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                          @Override
                          public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                          databaseReference.removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                           @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {


                           ProfileFragment prf = new ProfileFragment();

                          android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                          fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, prf).commit();


                                                        }
                                                    });


                                                }
                                            });


            @Override
                   public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError 
      databaseError) {

                  }
         })   ;




     }
  });
```

Comment: Can you post your database and a full source code, maybe a link to any repository

Comment: I don't even know what you are trying to commit after deleting from database

Comment: I am not authorized to share the whole code, sorry :( . Please see my latest comment.

Comment: Can you provide the VCS link here? preferably, github.com

Comment: One more thing that i had to do besides the code is to put a try catch block in the parent fragment (SinglePostFragment) where it fetches the same post. In this way after the post is deleted the code ignores fetching and there is no crashing.

Comment: @Zubayr Good Job!